# Trying to initialize ManagedObjectContext from Singleton class in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I created a Single View Application in iOS that also incorporates Core Data.  I moved my .xcdatamodel file from another application and put in to the one I am working on now, and I am having issues.  What I have done is cut and paste the code from the previous application and placed it in my AppDelegate.h/m files:

```
@interface DBAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

and my .m file:

```
    @implementation DBAppDelegate

    @synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
    @synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
    @synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
//the line below is what is causing an error
        DBViewController *controller = (DBViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;


        return YES;
    }
```

Within my .m file, I also included the boiler plate code for Core Data that was also in my previous application which I have not posted. In my new application, what I am doing is that I have created an access layer, which also provides a Singleton instance to access this layer.  It is in this class where I do my CRUD operations, and have declared the following properties in the .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

At the moment, I am getting the following error:

"Property 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type "DBViewController".  What I would like to do is initialize the managedObjectContext inside my method that allows for the creation of a Singleton instance:

```
static DB *sharedSingleton = nil;

+ (DB *) sharedInstance {

    if (sharedSingleton == nil) {

        sharedSingleton = [[super alloc] init];

  }

    return sharedSingleton;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I realize I don't declare a managedObjectContext object in my DBViewController, but what do I put in place of this line?  I figure it would be something with respect to my Singleton class, but I honestly don't have a clue here.

Comment: syedfa, please do consider reading this post [Core Data singleton manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6336308/1588258) before deciding to go for a Singleton Approach. The metric to decide being Memory Usage and Threading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is often called a "data store" singleton, and it's a good design pattern to use. What I do in my applications is have a singleton class named `DataStore`, you can call it whatever you wish, with a class method:

```
+ (id)sharedStore{
    static DataStore *sharedStore = nil;
    if (!sharedStore) {
        sharedStore = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedStore;
}
```

Whenever I need access to the resources provided by the datastore, I do:

```
Datastore *ds = [Datastore sharedStore];
```

To provide access to Core Data, I have a data store method:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext{
    static NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    if(context){
        return context;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = nil;

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    if (!coordinator) {
        coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:objectModel];
    }

    if(!coordinator){
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *storePath = [[self documentsDirectoryPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datastore.sqlite"];
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:storePath];

    NSError *error;

    if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:NULL error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Database error: %@", error);
        // if you make changes to your model and a database already exists in the app
        // you'll get a NSInternalInconsistencyException exception. When the model is updated
        // the databasefile must be removed. Remove the database here because it's easy.
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];

        //try to add the persistant store one more time. If it still fails then abort
        if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:NULL error:&error])
            return nil;
    }

    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    [context setUndoManager:nil];

    return context;

}
```

This method returns `nil` if an `NSManagedObjectContext` couldn't be created. This way you only need to do:

`NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[DataStore sharedStore] managedObjectContext];`

whenever you need to use Core Data. This can be done once in `viewDidLoad`.

Edit:

The `managedObjectContext` method uses the method below to find the documents directory:

```
+ (NSString *)documentsDirectoryPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  I used your solution but I'm getting the error: No known class method for selector 'documentsDirectoryPath'.  I am getting this error with the line: NSString *storePath = [[self documentsDirectoryPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datastore.sqlite"];  I put this method + (NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext{ } inside my DataStore class, correct?

Comment: See my edit. I forgot I use a method to find the documents directory.

Comment: Thanks once again for your prompt reply.  I am now getting the RuntimeException: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'User'.  In my DataStore class, I have the method, addUser, and in that method I have the following lines:  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[DB sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];//I put this line here instead of the viewDidLoad method.
    
    User *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];

Comment: As a follow up question, do I still need all the boiler plate code in my AppDelegate class, or can I remove that altogether?  Just wondering.

Comment: Are you still getting the exception? If so, are you certain you aren't getting back nil from +managedObjectContext? Also, this line is incorrect: NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[DataStore sharedStore] managedObjectContext];

Since +managedObjectContext is a class method, you don't need to access it through the singleton. You can access it directly via [Datastore managedObjectContext].

Comment: Thanks again.  I realized that my problem was that my .sqlite file was missing, and that I had to generate it.  Your solution helped me solve the original I was getting which is why I chose your answer.  My code is now working :-)